# Endomorphism algebra of irreducible module over a group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $0$, $G$ be a finite group, $V$ be an irreducible $F[G]$-module which is not absolutely irreducible, $E=\mathrm{End}_{ F[G]}(V)$.
Then by Schur's lemma $E$ is a skew field.
Take $0\neq v\in V$, it follows that $Ev=\{\sigma(v)\mid \sigma\in E\}$ is a $F$-linear subspace of $V$ with dimension less than or equal to $\dim_{F}(E)$.
In addition, assume that $\dim_F(E)=\dim_F(V)$.

**Question** Is there exists a vector $0\neq v_0\in V$ such that $Ev_0$ is a proper subspace of $V$ (i.e $\dim_{F}(Ev_0)<\dim_{F}(V)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not "less or equal", its "equal". There are no shenanigans with dimension over skew fields, a subspace generated by one non-zero vector is a line, and is isomorphic to $E$ (as an $E$-module, or $F$-vector space).

So no, for any $v_0\neq 0$, if $Ev_0\subseteq Ev$, then $Ev_0=Ev$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the sentence "There are no shenanigans with dimension over skew fields". @Captain Lama

Comment: Over an $F$-algebra $A$, if $M$ is an $A$-module, it is of course possible that $\dim_F(Av)<\dim_F(A)$ for $v\in M$ non-zero. But it is not possible when $A$ is a division algebra (a skew field), in that case there is a solid theory of dimension for $A$-modules, just like for vector spaces over fields.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! @Captain Lama

Answer (score 1):

Captain Lama has already given an answer. Here I would like to explain detailly.

**Theorem** Let $E$ be an unital ring. Then $E$ is a division ring (or skew field) if and only if every left $E$-module is free. (see https://planetmath.org/ringswhoseeverymoduleisfree)

Take $0\neq v\in V$, by this theorem, $f:E\rightarrow Ev$ where $e\mapsto ev$ for $e\in E$ is an isomorphism of $E$-modules. So
$$
\sum_i k_i(e_iv)=0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_i (k_ie_i)v=0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_i k_ie_i=0
$$
where the last iff holds as $E$ being a division ring. Thus $\dim_FE=\dim_FEv$ for all $0\neq v\in V$, and the answer for the question is no since the assumption $\dim_FE=\dim_FV$.